# C++: How do I pass this pointer into this class?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

Here's a simple piece of code. What I want help with is the two places I've writen "???".

The goal is to pass a temporary pointer to the container-class which then becomes the unique owner of that object. However, I do not know what to write in the two places where I've writen "???".

In particular, what do I write in the initializer-list, and what do I write when I actually instantiate my container-class?

```
class abstractBase
{
    virtual void method() = 0;
};

class derived : public abstractBase
{
    // ...
};

class container
{
    std::unique_ptr<abstractBase> ptr;
    container(std::unique<abstractBase> input)
        : ??? //What do I write here to make input = ptr?
    {}
};

int main()
{
container instance(???) //what do I write here to pass a temporary ptr of type derived?
}
```

For the first one, I thought maybe

`: ptr(std::move(input))`

would be the way?

For the second one, I am not sure. Maybe just `std::make_unique<derived> input`?

Comment: I'd recommend a virtual destructor for abstractBase. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [std::move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) and [std::make_unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) should do the trick here:

```
class container
{
    std::unique_ptr<abstractBase> ptr;

public:
    container(std::unique_ptr<abstractBase> input)
        : ptr(std::move(input))
    {}
};

int main()
{
    container instance(std::make_unique<derived>());
}
```

You might also wanna have a look at [this article](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2014/07/should-move-only-types-ever-be-passed.html) concerning sink parameters and move-only types.